# Too many buttons in an iOS application

Tags: ios, notification

I'm working on an iOS application in which one of the main screens contains several buttons and a notification. This notification must be clear as it provides essential information for using the app.

It is common, particularly in Web apps, for notifications to appear at the top right of an application (such as on Facebook).

I can solve the problem of multiple buttons on Android by using a floating button at the bottom and the notification at the top right.

**The iOS version is currently as follows:**

[image]

The notification is a "floating button" at the bottom and the other buttons are around the screen. I wanted to avoid this Android pattern in the iOS version.

**Should I leave the notification at the bottom (ignoring the common pattern) or leave it at the top right? Where would I put the other buttons?** There are four buttons: Share, Play, Like and Hide (Hide will be implemented)

Comment: I am having a very hard time deciphering what you've written. Did you use machine translation into English?

Comment: I have reworded it slightly to make the question clearer. I hope I have understood what you are asking, Andre.

Comment: Yes, sorry for this English Google translate

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

I will go for something like this:

[image: Balsamiq mock]

Where navigation is on a top level navigation (to either exit or go to notifications) and a bottom level for item-related actions (like, play, share, hide).

If the Notifications are related to an especific item, i will suggest to just post it below the the item description.